# Retrieve Max loaded date across all tables on a DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Output I'm trying to get to;

(Database name = ATT)

1. Table Name
2. Column name
3. MAX loaded date = MAX(loaded_date) for this column only

loaded_date is a column in around 50 tables in a database with the same name and datatype (Datetime)

```
select * FROM sys.tables 
select * FROM syscolumns
```

I've been exploring the system tables without much luck,  looking at some posts it may be done dynamic SQL which I've never done.

Comment: What does `MAX(loaded_date) for this column only` mean? Is `loaded_date` another column? What would the results look like? Sample input would help also

Comment: My bad Dale .  i shouldn't have added the  **for this column only

Comment: Then what is point 2 supposed to represent? Just confused about what actual results you want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an sql that writes an sql..

```
SELECT REPLACE(
  'select ''{tn}'' as table_name, max(loaded_date) as ld from {tn} union all'
  ,'{tn}',table_name)
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE 
  column_name = 'loaded_date'
```

Run that, then copy all but the final UNION ALL out of the results window and into the query window, and run again

---

If you wanted to get all this into a single string for dynamic exec, i guess it'd look like (untested) a procedure that contained:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @x =
  STRING_AGG(
    REPLACE(
    'select ''{tn}'' as table_name, max(loaded_date) as ld from {tn}'
    ,'{tn}',table_name)
  ,' union all ') 
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE 
  column_name = 'loaded_date';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @x;
```

If your SQLS is old and doesnt have string_agg it's a bit more awkward - but there are many examples of "turn rows into CSV" in sql server that look like `STUFF..FOR XML PATH` - https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=rows+to+CSV+SQLS&ia=web

Comment: Thank you Caius Jard
I really appreciate the above. 
I've run the code and it outputs the columns that i need however, how can i run this without having to copy it out . im trying to automate the process maybe even insert the output into a seprate table  at a later date . whats your thoughts ?

Comment: Erm.. It hugely depends on what code will run it. If it's a front end language like C# or JS, then you can just select it like it is, make it into a single big string and run it like any other SQL. Similarly if youre doing it like in a stored procedure you can collect it all into an nvarchar(max) and then EXEC it - if your SQLServer is recent it might have STRING_AGG (i'll post an idea on it) which would make it easier too... **BUT** it kinda seems like you might have a flaw in the data modelling here.. You have this data spread out across lots of tables - **WHY?** is what i wonder.. Usually..

Comment: ..when people say that they then answer with "because I have 50 tables that are all identical schema but it's one table per client" or something, and the table name has thus become some sort of partitioning device, which tbh is a fairly terrible idea because it leads to these nasty hacks. The table name is storing stuff that should be in a column in one table - it would be better if all the 50 tables are merged into 1 with an extra column of CLIENT_NAME or whatever, to separate the clients. If you need to provide legacy compatibility you can also create a set of VIEW that are like ..

Comment: .. `CREATE VIEW tblMicrosoft AS SELECT * FROM AllClients WHERE ClientName = 'Microsoft'` - and apps can carry on selecting it (or even inserting to it using a instead of trigger) while you slowly upgrade all the system to use `AllClients`. Of course, there's a chance this doesnt apply to you but if it does, and tables are "same structure but keep data separate for reason X" it's better to not do that

Comment: the tables are all different but because DB is updated regularly externally by third parties the loaded date is the last column that lives in each table. similar to how a DW has an updated date. forgive me I'm still learning SQL .

Comment: 'NVARCHAR' is not a recognized CURSOR option.

Comment: I got the above error I tried adding  @x is this the right approach?

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos in the sql-see answer edit

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a more permanent type of script that does this. It returns a result set of the list of tables in the current database with a column named `loaded_date` along with the `MAX(loaded_date)` result from each table. This script individually queries each table by looping through and running the query on each table individually and keeping track of the max value for each table in a table variable. It also has a `@Debug` variable that allows you to see the text of the queries that would be run instead of actually running them and implements custom error message to troubleshoot any issues.

```
/*disable row count messages*/
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

/*set to 1 to debug (aka just print queries instead of running)*/
DECLARE @Debug bit = 0; 

/*get list of tables to query and assign a unique index to row to assist in looping*/
DECLARE @TableList TABLE(
    SchemaAndTableName nvarchar(257) NOT NULL
    ,OrderToQuery bigint NOT NULL 
    ,MaxLoadedDate datetime NULL 
    ,PRIMARY KEY (OrderToQuery)
); 
INSERT INTO @TableList (SchemaAndTableName,OrderToQuery) 
SELECT 
    CONCAT(QUOTENAME(s.name),N'.', QUOTENAME(t.name)) AS SchemaAndTableName
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.name, t.name) AS OrderToQuery
FROM 
    sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
    c.name = N'loaded_date'; 
    
/*declare and set some variables for loop*/
DECLARE @NumTables int = (SELECT TOP (1) OrderToQuery FROM @TableList ORDER BY OrderToQuery DESC); 
DECLARE @I int = 1;
DECLARE @CurMaxDate datetime; 
DECLARE @CurTable nvarchar(257);
DECLARE @CurQuery nvarchar(max); 
/*start loop*/
WHILE @I <= @NumTables
BEGIN 
    /*build text of current query*/
    SET @CurTable = (SELECT SchemaAndTableName FROM @TableList WHERE OrderToQuery = @I); 
    SET @CurQuery = CONCAT(N'SELECT @MaxDateOut = MAX(loaded_date) FROM ', @CurTable, N';'); 
    /*check debugging status*/ 
    IF @Debug = 0
    BEGIN 
        BEGIN TRY 
            EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @CurQuery
                ,@params = N'@MaxDateOut datetime OUTPUT'
                ,@MaxDateOut = @CurMaxDate OUTPUT; 
        END TRY 
        BEGIN CATCH 
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(max) = CONCAT(
                N'Error querying table ', @CurTable, N'.', NCHAR(13), NCHAR(10)
                ,N'Errored query: ', NCHAR(13), NCHAR(10), @CurQuery, NCHAR(13), NCHAR(10)
                ,N'Error message: ', ERROR_MESSAGE()
            ); 
            RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1) WITH NOWAIT;
            /*on error end loop so error can be investigated*/
            SET @I = @NumTables + 1; 
        END CATCH; 
    END; 
    ELSE /*currently debugging*/ 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT(CONCAT(N'Debug output: ', @CurQuery)); 
    END; 
   /*update value in our table variable*/
   UPDATE @TableList 
   SET MaxLoadedDate = @CurMaxDate
   WHERE 
        OrderToQuery = @I; 
    /*increment loop*/ 
    SET @I = @I + 1;
END; 

SELECT 
    SchemaAndTableName AS TableName
    ,MaxLoadedDate AS Max_Loaded_date 
FROM 
    @TableList;
```

I like this solution better as querying each table one at a time would be much less system impact than attempting one large `UNION ALL` query. Querying a large set of a tables all at once could cause some serious resource semaphore or locking contention (depending on usage of your db).

It is fairly well commented, but let me know if something is not clear.

Also, just a note, dynamic SQL should be used as a last resort. I provided this script to answer your question, but you should explore better options than something like this.

Comment: Hi Trenton-ftw
Thank you for the above I really appreciate it, I've tried it, and as you've stated it only spits out a single value. i need to include the table name in the output 
see the below eg; 
 
TableName Max_Loaded_date
table1 2021-07-16
table2 2021-07-15
table3 2021-07-16
table4 2021-07-14

Comment: @Huss1 ah sorry about that. I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to the max `loaded_date` across all tables. I can edit for that scenario.

Comment: @Huss1 alright answer has been updated to return the list of tables with their `MAX(loaded_date)` instead of a single maximum `loaded_date` across all tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for undocumented stored procedure `sp_MSforeachtable`. But, don't use in production code, as this stored procedure might not be available in future versions.

[Read more on sp_MSforeachtable](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-introduction-to-sp_msforeachtable-run-commands-iteratively-through-all-tables-in-a-database/)

```sql
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT ''?'' as tablename, max(loaded_Date) FROM ?'
```

Comment: thanks venkataraman-r  i  tried adding Union all keep getting error